# Помощь в запуске rnnlib

Tags: python, ubuntu

Кто имел дело с rnnlib, подскажите по такому вопросу:
все нормально скомпилировалось, но не могу запустить ни один пример, вылазит такая ошибка:
[image: ошибка]

Пытался найти netcdf_helpers, не нашел. В пакетах netcdf его нет. Возможно ли как то исправить данное недоразумение? 
З.Ы. все делал в убунту

Comment: Как я понимаю, может быть проблема с PYTHONPATH, вдруг будет полезен в таком случае этот материал: https://docs.webfaction.com/software/python.html#importerror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен, не там искал. Изначально думал что файл должен идти с каким нибудь пакетом, оказалось что он мирно лежит в папке utils